# When create an image carousel, error: Property does not exist on type 'Element'. ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to create a carousel slideshow using a few images from a tutorial from w3schools however it seems that there's an error in the JavaScript file and the error is coming from the `.style.display` section from JavaScript.

The error that's shown is:

> Property 'style' does not exist on type  'Element'. ts(2339)

I've tried to my best to fixed but can't solve it.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="script.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
<p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="green.jpeg" alt="Trees"> 
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="map.jpeg" alt="Trees"> 
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="trees.jpeg" alt="Trees"> 
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript :

```
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbaiH.png)1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
`
```

Comment: That’s a TypeScript error not a JavaScript error; since you’re not using TypeScript, you can disable this in your IDE; linter warnings (e.g. ESLint or JSHint), however, might come in handy. Unrelatedly, your code won’t do anything, because it’s executed before the DOM is ready. Use `<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>` to fix that.

Comment: _“I've tried to my best to fixed but can't solve it”_ — Fix what? The “error” itself? [Google](//google.com/search?q=Property+style+does+not+exist+on+type+Element) has over 88 million results about this error message. Also, instead of `className`, please use the [`classList` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).